# How to throw multiple exceptions in Java main class

Tags: java, exception

Will this work correctly (it compiles). Or is there a better way for me to throw multiple exceptions when calling the Java main() class?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
                         throws AWTException, IOException{}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of explicitly throwing exceptions in main() ? Isn't this the last "chain"; every uncaught exception will eventually get here, right? I'm just asking...

Comment: no idea, maybe that's a good question to ask to the entire StackOverflow community in a question by itself. I've got very little experience with these matters. The only reason I throw them in main is because I don't know how or where else to do it to get my program to do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will work.  But for future reference, if you find yourself throwing multiple exceptions that are similar and are recovered from in the same manner, see if they both inherit from the same parent exception other than java.lang.Exception.  If so, you can throw that instead.  You can always just throw Exception itself (and nothing else) but that brings up some best-practice issues.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't write some code and test it, you are half way there. It looks fine. The method `main` is not usually called by anyone. If that is case, there is no need to declare the `throws` clause.

Comment: He also wants to know if it's the best way to do it. Not something you test easily for.